# Pictures in grid displays differently in different broswers

Tags: html, css, css-grid

So I'm trying to make a grid of some icons:

```css
.wrapper {
    border: medium solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
    font-size: 1vmax;
}

.icons-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 80%;
    width: 98%;
    padding: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    pointer-events: none;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 14.2857%);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    gap: 1%;
}

.icon-item {
    height: 80%;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.icon-item-wrapper {
    height: calc(100% - 1em);
}

.icon-item-icon {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="icons-wrapper">
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000" height="100%"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000" height="100%"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000" height="100%"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000" height="100%"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000" height="100%"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000" height="100%"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000" height="100%"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000" height="100%"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000" height="100%"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Interestingly, I received three different results in different browsers.

I'm running the browsers on macOS 10.14.6, if that's relevant.

In Chrome 86/Opera 71 (which is the expected result, by the way):
[image: Chrome/Opera]

In Firefox 80:
[image: Firefox]

In Safari 12.1:
[image: Safari]

Untested in IE and Edge, but I suppose it's only going to be worse.

There's also this weird bug (in all browsers) that prevents it from displaying properly before you resize the window. Say, if you run the above snippet in Chrome, everything will turn up in the middle at first (the width is broken, pretty much like the Firefox screenshot above), but if you go full-page and back it will display normally as the screenshot.

I know grid is a relatively new feature and still has bugs, but this is just frustrating. Any ideas why?

---

**Edit:** OK, with focus.style's answer I'm able to get it working on Chrome and Firefox. However, the content still overflows in Safari (although it's at least visible this time):
[image: Safari 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can agree that `display: grid;` is a bit raw, but it's already a pretty nice and powerful tool. However, in this case there is an issue with automatic scale or inner child tag `<img>`

Firstly - don't use attribute `height="100%"` in `<img>`, it's bit outdated. You can set height in CSS. Removed them in my example.

Secondly - in `.icon-item-icon` you have only `height: 100%;`. But the actual size of the image is 1000x1000px. And at this point different browsers scales image width (inside of a `grid` cell) in different ways. To prevent such behave, I've add `max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;` to image and removed `height: 100%` (because of issues in Safari), so now it can't be larger then it's parent. Now everything works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari (tested).

```css
.wrapper {
    border: medium solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
    font-size: 1vmax;
}

.icons-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 80%;
    width: 98%;
    padding: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    pointer-events: none;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 14.2857%);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    gap: 1%;
}

.icon-item {
    height: 80%;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.icon-item-wrapper {
    height: calc(100% - 1em);
}

.icon-item-icon {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="icons-wrapper">
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATED**

There are always some problems with height of an image in grid cells... Rewrited the cod a bit. Added an `object-fit: contain;` solution to `.icon-item-icon`.

Although changed `grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 1fr);` in `.icons-wrapper`.

There is a strange behave in Safari, when we use grid pith `position: absolute`. Some cells height issue. Not sure, it may be some Safari bug. Rewrited wrapper for now.

```css
.wrapper {
    border: medium solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
    font-size: 1vmax;
}

.icons-wrapper {
    height: 80vh;
    width: 98%;
    padding: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    pointer-events: none;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    gap: 1%;
}

.icon-item {
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.icon-item-wrapper {
    height: calc(100% - 1em);
    position: relative;
}

.icon-item-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="icons-wrapper">
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-item">
                <div class="icon-item-wrapper"><img class="icon-item-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000"></div>
                <div class="icon-item-text">Text</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you so much! One small question though: why does setting `grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 1fr);` instead of `14.2857%` generate different results? The former doesn't seem to respect the height of the grid (80%).

Comment: Oh no! Now the content overflows in Safari again…

Comment: Updated the answer a lot. Look please.